# how show notification information

Tags: php, codeigniter

how to show notification "NPM Kosong" if i have 3 condition on model.    and how to make on controller for show the notification.

case 1: if condition cek_npm is empty = notif "NPM empty. check again!"
case 2: if condition cek_npm is not empty = notif "NPM success for absent" 
case 3: if condition npm_mhs and kode_absensi is not empty = notif "NPM have been absent" thanks you and i am sorry my english is bad.

my model

```
public function cek_npm($arr){
    $arr['npm_mhs']       = $this->input->post('npm_mhs'); 
    $datenow=date("Y-m-d");
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');
    //$now = date("H:i:s");
    $jam_masuk_absensi="";

    $query=$this->db->query("select npm_mhs from tbl_mahasiswa where npm_mhs= '" . $arr['npm_mhs'] . "'");
    if($query->num_rows()==0){

        $this->session->set_flashdata('info', 'NPM tidak ditemukkan ');
        //return $query->num_rows();
        return null;
    }   

    $query1=$this->db->query("select kode_absensi from tbl_absensi where npm_mhs='" . $arr['npm_mhs'] . "' and tgl_absensi='$datenow'");

    if($query1->num_rows()>0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    else{
        $data=array(
             'npm_mhs'=>$arr['npm_mhs'],
             'kode_absensi'=>'1',
             'jam_masuk_absensi'=>date('H:i:s'),
             'tgl_absensi'=>$datenow
            );
        $this->db->insert('tbl_absensi',$data);
        return true;
    }



}
```

my controller:

```
public function insert_absensi()
{
    $arr['npm_mhs']       = trim($this->input->post('npm_mhs')); 

    if($this->absensi_model->cek_npm($arr['npm_mhs']) == TRUE){

        $this->session->set_flashdata('info', 'NPM ditemukan sukses absen ');


    }
    else{

        $this->session->set_flashdata('info', 'NPM sudah absen');   

    }
    if($this->absensi_model->cek_npm($arr['npm_mhs']) == null)

    $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'NPM kosong');   

}
```

my view:

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    $("#form").validate({
        submitHandler: function (form) {
                $.post("<?php echo base_url(); ?>absensi_c/insert_absensi", {
                    npm_mhs: $('#npm_mhs').val(),




                },
                function (data) {
                    window.location = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>absensi_c";
                    //$('#loadpage').html(data);
                });


        }
    });

});

function batal() {
    window.location = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>absensi_c";
}
```